# Rails 3: When a Collection is Rendered, does it Access a Controller For Each Instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, controller, render

A user can have many posts, and each post can have many comments. When visiting a user's profile, you get a list of posts rendered like so in the view:

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

I want to also render the comments for each post by doing something like:

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

However, where would I declare @comments? If I declare it in user#show, then I'd get all the comments for the user, as opposed to the comments for a specific post.

So when a collection is rendered, does it access a controller for each instance? If so, what controller method is it using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render each post's comments inside the post partial:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render post %>
  <%= render :partial => 'posts_comments', :collection => post.comments %>
<% end %>
```

This does not go to the controller on each `post.comments` statement, it just queries the DB.

You can also eliminate the multiple queries by setting the @posts instance variable in the controller in the following way:

```
@posts = @user.posts.includes(:comments)
```

Then when you do `post.comments` it will not query the DB, but load the comments from the memory.

Comment: So my question is somewhat oversimplified, as I was just trying to find out if it was possible use a controller here. In fact, I typically take the first approach you describe, though the second sounds preferable, now that you've pointed it out. The problem I'm having is that I'm calling an Application_Controller method in the partial, and for some reason the instances declared within the view do not carry over to the method. Unfortunately, this is a whole other issue. Perhaps I should just accept your (very excellent) response and then write a new question?

Comment: If you think the question asked was answered then yes, please mark it as accepted and ask another one describing your other problem, I promise to try and solve it for you as well.

Comment: After a little experimentation, I solved the problem by passing the necessary variables as arguments. It looks like the @ sign only shares variable between standard controllers and views. For some reason, it doesn't share them with the Application_Controller.